# Error with username/password checker in C++

Tags: c++, password-checker

I am currently attempting to learn some basic C++ programming and decided to make myself a  basic 3 attempt username and password checker to practice some of what I have read up on.  Problem is when I run the program and enter an incorrect username and password first, the program will no longer recognize the correct username and password if entered on the second or third attempt.  I have been looking at this for quite some time now and can't seem to get it to work.
I have even included a currently commented out line to make sure that the program is reading the proper inputs, which it is.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int attempts=0;
    string username, password;
    while (attempts < 3)
    {
        cout<<"\nPlease enter your username and password seperated by a space.\n";
        getline( cin, username, ' ');
        cin>>password;
        if (username == "Ryan" && password == "pass")
        {
            cout<<"\nYou have been granted access.";
            return 0;
            cin.get();
        }
        else
        {
            attempts++;
            //cout<<username <<" " <<password << "\n";
            cout<<"Incorrect username or password, try again.";
            cout<<"\nAttempts remaining: "<<3-attempts <<"\n";
        }
    }
    cout<<"\nOut of attempts, access denied.";
    cin.get();

}
```

Any help or critique is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Btw., the `return 0; cin.get();` in the `if` block makes no sense. A `return` is the end of the whole function, the `cin.get();` won´t get executed.

Comment: Yeah, I think that got left behind from early stages or something. Thanks for pointing it out though. I could definitely use to get in to the habit of going back and cleaning up after myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your username includes a newline character '\n' after the first attempt due to getline

Changing your cin usage from

```
getline( cin, username, ' ');
cin>>password;
```

to

```
cin >> username;
cin >> password;
```

fixes your problem

Comment: If you don't mind me asking then what dictates the program knowing to split the input at the space?  I honestly didn't think it would split like that to be checked but instead would take the entire input and throw it in as the value of 'username'.

Comment: It is standard behavior of the cin stream: it reads a string up to the first separator token, which is a blank

Comment: @Ryan The *extraction operator* `>>` splits input at spaces and newlines. It basically skips any initial spaces, then reads in until it meets another space and stops.